# Laravel: setting the values of config file from database

Tags: laravel

I have created a custom disk such as

```
'custom-ftp' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => 'imn.tra.de',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'port'     => 21,
            'ssl'      => true,
        ],
```

but i want the username and password to be set by each user in my database and call the disk accordingly,

rightnow what i am doing is before uploading the file to ftp, im doing

```
 $user = Auth::user();
    $setting = $user->setting;

    Config::set('filesystems.disk.custom-ftp.username', $setting->user_name);
    Config::set('filesystems.disk.custom-ftp.password', $setting->password);
```

And later

```
  Storage::disk('custom-ftp')->put($file, $localFile);
```

But i am getting
Like this : Could not login with connection: imn.tra.de::21, username: as this is still picking the username from config where it is empty

Comment: You can add settings field to users table and set them from your dashboard or you can use some settings package.
Where is some tutorial for you https://laracasts.com/lessons/managing-mass-user-settings

Comment: I am already doing saving the settings in database and updating the config file before uploading the file to ftp, kindly review my edited question

Comment: What is the problem with your aproach? It's not working?

Comment: I am getting the username and password are empty, i think it is picking the values from the config file where username and password are emtpry

Comment: Like this : Could not login with connection: imn.tra.de::21, username: as this is still picking the username from config where it is empty

Comment: Config files are used for static settings. Dynamic settings shouldn't be put in config this way

Comment: You may set configuration variables at runtime by passing an array of key / value pairs. However, note that this function only affects the configuration value for the current request and does not update your actual configuration values:

config(['app.debug' => true]); (https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-config)

Comment: The key is `disks` and not `disk`. So try `filesystems.disks.custom-ftp.username`

Comment: Finally it works, thanks

Comment: How did it finally work?  we are curious

Comment: It was a typing error i used disks instead of disk, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Config files are used for static settings and are meant only for settings specific to application not to user.

Dynamic settings shouldn't be put in config.

You should create FTP driver on the fly:

```
$ftp = Storage::createFtpDriver([
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => 'imn.tra.de',
    'username' => $setting->user_name,
    'password' => $setting->password,
    'port'     => 21,
    'ssl'      => true,
]);

$ftp->put($file, $localFile);
```

Reusable solution would look like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserFtpStorageService
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $userSettings = Auth::user()->settings;
        $this->ftp = Storage::createFtpDriver([
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => 'imn.tra.de',
            'username' => $userSettings->user_name,
            'password' => $userSettings->password,
            'port'     => 21,
            'ssl'      => true,
        ]);
    }

    public function put(string $path, $contents, $options = []) : bool
    {
        return $this->ftp->put($path, $contents, $options);
    }
}
```

And then you use it like:

```
(new UserFtpStorageService())->put($path, $contents);
```

Comment: How this can be used in future? like lets say we use this for uploading file one time, then next time do we need to create ftpdriver again?

Comment: You can just create a class that abstracts it all an do something like: `UserFtpStorage::put($file, $localFile)`

Comment: @user8076689 I added example to my answer